# MySQL select the nearest lower value in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL table that stores running times and a score associated with each time on the table.

```
/////////////////////
/ Time    *   Score /
/ 1531    *    64   /
/ 1537    *    63   /
/ 1543    *    61   /
/ 1549    *    60   /
/////////////////////
```

This is an example of 4 rows in the table. My question is how do I select the nearest lowest time.

**EXAMPLE**: If someone records a time of 1548 I want to return the score for 1543 (**not** 1549) which is 61.

Is there an SQL query I can use to do this thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use SQL's `WHERE` clause to filter the records, its `ORDER BY` clause to sort them and `LIMIT` (in MySQL) to obtain only the first result:

```
SELECT   Score
FROM     my_table
WHERE    Time <= 1548
ORDER BY Time DESC
LIMIT    1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/912a3/1/0).

Comment: Perfect thanks wondering if you know how to get this to work in php this is the code i have but I am getting an error                        $run_time_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM male_run_time WHERE Time=" . $run_time . "ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1") 
   or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @psycho: (1) the error message will tell you what's wrong - why didn't you quote it here? (2) it's likely to be due to the lack of SQL whitespace between the `$run_time` literal and the `ORDER BY` keywords. (3) you appear to have changed `<=` in my SQL to `=` in yours. (4) the `ext/mysql` extension (which provides the `mysql_query()` function is ancient, unsupported and deprecated as of PHP v5.5 - its use in new code has been strongly advised against for the past two years. (5) you really ought to learn about parameterising prepared statements to protect against injection attacks.

Comment: Hi sorry here is the error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY Time DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: you need to make space before word ORDER  -> `" ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1"`

Comment: Thank you I have fixed the syntax error but the query is not returning values listed in the table e.g. 1548. But it will return a number that is in the table. How do i get it to select the nearest lower number

Comment: Sorry, do you want to select the `Time` or the `Score` from the "nearest lower value"?  I understood from your question that you wanted the `Score`, but your comment implies you want the `Time`.  Perhaps you want both?  In any event, just change the `SELECT` list accordingly: `SELECT Time FROM ...` or `SELECT Time, Score FROM ...`.